# How to check integer value in a field using mysql

Tags: mysql

I am having a field in a table with type varchar and their value looks similar to

1. red-chief-men-245-brown-94581
2. adidas-men-agora-93945
3. kids-shoes

In this i need to get only values that ends with hypen followed by integer ex ("-94581" , "-93945") ..

Is there any way in mysql to get that

Comment: U can use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index to cut `X` chars from end of string

Comment: exactly what skowron-line say +1

Comment: @skowron-line: That does not check for numbers

Comment: @juergen d its not number, he has varchar field after cutting it still will be string, substring_index will not cast it to number

Comment: @skowron-line: yes. And he wants to check for numbers at the end of his string which substring() can't.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`RLIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) operator in place of `LIKE`.  This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo RLIKE '.*-[[:digit:]]*$'
```

Comment: This one worked for me with slight modification SELECT * FROM table WHERE foo RLIKE '.*-[[:digit:]]{3,}$'

Answer (score 0):

Probably like this:

```
select  substr(searchfield,locate('_',searchfield)) as extractedfield from 
mytable where substr(searchfield,locate('_',searchfield)) > 0;
```